# aws-efs "ProvisioningFailed - no volume plugin matched" in k8s pvc

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I deployed efs-provisioner to mount aws-efs in k8s as pvc. Then I'm getting "no volume plugin matched" error while creating pvc.

```
$ kubectl describe pvc efs -n dev
Name:       efs
Namespace:  dev
StorageClass:   aws-efs
Status:     Pending
Volume:     
Labels:     <none>
Annotations:    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class=aws-efs
Capacity:   
Access Modes:   
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                SubObjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                -------------   --------    ------          -------
  32m       2m      21  persistentvolume-controller         Warning     ProvisioningFailed  no volume plugin matched

 kind: StorageClass
 apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
 metadata:
   name: aws-efs
 provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-efs
```

efs-provisioner-dep.yml at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/master/aws/efs/deploy/deployment.yaml

Comment: Do you have the [EFS provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/v5.2.0/aws/efs#efs-provisioner) running in your cluster? Is [the RBAC config correct](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/issues/754#issuecomment-449519952)?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Yes. efs-provisioner pod is up and running along RBAC. I followed the steps given in efs-provisioner github repo.

Comment: Do the efs-provisioner logs have anything interesting to say? And what about the logs of the controller-manager(s)?

Comment: [efs-provisioner logs] "Started provisioner controller kubernetes.io/aws-efs_efs-provisioner-7cc9c8fbff-lqxhw_0b01d56f-207b-11e9-8184-0a5864600209!"
----------
[controller-mnanager logs] "error finding provisioning plugin for claim acdc-dev/efs: no volume plugin matched
I0127 20:33:04.230303       1 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"acdc-dev", Name:"efs", UID:"8da02cd5-2272-11e9-9eec-0693f1251186", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"527618", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'ProvisioningFailed' no volume plugin matched"

@MatthewLDaniel

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `kubectl get -o yaml storageclass aws-efs` and similarly with `deploy efs-provisioner`

Answer (score 1):

I know this bit old and efs provisioner is officially deprecated. But still see some of the clusters and customers using it. I had the same issue and spend quite sometime troubleshooting it and I believe this can be helpful to someone who got the same issue.

I faced the issue after upgrading the efs provisoner to the latest numbered version which is  v2.4.0 which can be found [here](https://quay.io/repository/external_storage/efs-provisioner?tab=tags)

It was exactly went to the state as described in the question after the upgrade but I can confirm that it has started working after reverting back to the old version in my case v0.1.2.

After spending sometime, carefully analyzing the answers in [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/issues/1111) github issue I was able to fix it with below changes.

1. Changing the StorageClass prvisioner from `kubernetes.io/aws-efs` to something else such as `example.com/aws-efs`
2. Updating the efs provisioner deployment with the updated provisioner as below in the environment variables

```
         env:
           - name: FILE_SYSTEM_ID
             value: "{{ .Values.efs_fs_id }}"
           - name: AWS_REGION
             value: "{{ .Values.region }}"
           - name: PROVISIONER_NAME
             value: "example.com/aws-efs"
```

Make sure to delete the previous StorageClass with `kubernetes.io/aws-efs` before create the new one with the updated provisioner.

I hope this helps. Thanks.